# knockout data-bind expression to show string if value not defined

Tags: knockout.js

Currently I am putting a '-' if the value is zero with the below code:

```
<span data-bind="text: setup==0 ? '-' : setup"></span>
```

Rather than putting value: 0 in parts of my view-model data, I am trying to bind to a value that may in some instances not exist and in that instance display a string instead (my example is a '-' below), my binding code is below:

```
<span data-bind="text: (typeof setup !="undefined") ? setup : '-'"></span>
```

However, the binding is triggered each time for setup, in the json data below note the middle setup is not defined I would like to handle this case also.

```
var serverOptions = [
    {
        name: "DELL R210",
        setup: 1000
    },
    {
        name: "DELL R710",
    },
    {
        name: "DELL R720 Dual CPU",
        setup: 1000
    }
];
```

Scratching my head with the above, would appreciate pointers.

Comment: Add jsFiddle with the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in other SO posts, you can use $data to check if data exists

```
<span data-bind="text: !$data.setup ? '-' : $data.setup"></span>
```

If there is no text then this would evaluate to false, and show the - else show setup.

One note is that if you simply did $data.setup it is not a logical test, but adding the ! to the beginning turns it into one for evaluation purposes.

http://jsfiddle.net/NGNhD/1/